# Automatic folder approval

Tags: 2010, folder, project-server

We are creating folders every day via Project Web App and SharePoint 2010, and as of right now they are manually approved.

Folders in our company are always allowed to be approved so my question is:

How can we make this work. I have access to SharePoint Designer to edit or add workflows.

Comment: Can you please elaborate exactly what you are trying to do, and where? Do you want approval for documents, but automatic for folders?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Workflow associated with the folder content type ([2007](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30452/SharePoint-Workflows-for-Folder-Content-Type), should be OOB in 2010+), or create a workflow associated with your document library/libraries that approves items when filesize is less than 1 kB. One of the available workflow actions is to approve an item. Be sure to make the workflow start upon item creation!